# Multiple Report (Report will be same but Data/Calculation will be different) in a single RDLC report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, visual-studio-2017

I need to show BULK of reports in a single RDLC report viewer. I generated single report using RDLC report with dynamic images. But now I need to generate same report but in multiple numbers where data/calculation will be different. Code for single report generate is given below.

```
rdlcTax.Visible = true;
rdlcTax.Reset();
rdlcTax.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rdlcTax.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Tax" + dt.Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();
rdlcTax.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/rdlcTaxCertificate.rdlc";
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsTaxCertificate", dt);
var param = new ReportParameter[] {
          new ReportParameter("fromDate", fromMonth.Replace("-", " ")),
          new ReportParameter("toDate", toMonth.Replace("-", " ")),
          new ReportParameter("rateOfDeduction", rateOfDeduction + "%"),
          new ReportParameter("name", name),
          new ReportParameter("address", address),
          new ReportParameter("refNo", refNo),
          new ReportParameter("issueDate", issueDate),
          new ReportParameter("amount", tdsSum.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.')[0]),
          new ReportParameter("amountWord", textInfo.ToTitleCase(int.Parse(tdsSum.ToString()).ToText()) + " Taka Only"),
          new ReportParameter("imagePath", imagePath, true)
};

rdlcTax.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
rdlcTax.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
rdlcTax.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
rdlcTax.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
rdlcTax.DataBind();
rdlcTax.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

I also tried loop for generate multiple report in same report viewer, but did not work. Report shows only data from last DataTable. Codes are given below.

```
rdlcTax.Visible = true;
rdlcTax.Reset();
rdlcTax.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
rdlcTax.LocalReport.DisplayName = "Tax Certificate";
rdlcTax.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/rdlcTaxCertificateBulk.rdlc";
rdlcTax.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
rdlcTax.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
     var name = dt.Rows[0]["NAME"].ToString();
     var address = dt.Rows[0]["ADDRESS"].ToString();
     var refNo = dt.Rows[0]["REFERENCE_NO"].ToString();
     var issueDate = dt.Rows[0]["ISSUE_DATE"].ToString();
     var tdsSum = Math.Round(double.Parse(dt.Compute("Sum(TDS_AMOUNT)", "").ToString()));

     ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsTaxCertificate", dt);
     var param = new ReportParameter[] {
            new ReportParameter("fromDate", fromMonth.Replace("-", " ")),
            new ReportParameter("toDate", toMonth.Replace("-", " ")),
                            new ReportParameter("rateOfDeduction", rateOfDeduction + "%"),
            new ReportParameter("name", name),
            new ReportParameter("address", address),
            new ReportParameter("refNo", refNo),
            new ReportParameter("issueDate", issueDate),
            new ReportParameter("amount", tdsSum.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.')[0]),
            new ReportParameter("amountWord", textInfo.ToTitleCase(int.Parse(tdsSum.ToString()).ToText()) + " Taka Only"),
            new ReportParameter("imagePath", imagePath, true)
     };

     rdlcTax.LocalReport.SetParameters(param);
     rdlcTax.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
     rdlcTax.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
     rdlcTax.DataBind();
     rdlcTax.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

In code where I have to modify to generate multiple report?

Answer (score 0):

What the purpose of having parameter in your bulk report? This is based on your code snippet like to understand the requirement.

Is all columns names are same in your Tables?

```
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
****
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply. actually i have solved the problem using subreport.